# Deleat Rows with condition to another column in dataframe

Tags: r

I have this dataframe of 4 columns and I want to delete those rows which are not less than equal to difference of 100 to col_A

```
User    Col_A   Col_B   Col_C
   a    1450    1450    1250
   b    1450    1450    1440
   c    1320    1280    1225
   d    1300    1300    1190
   e    1295    1250    1200
   f    1295    1295    1250
   g    1295    1240    1000
   h    1295    1295    1260
   j    1295    1295    1260
   k    1295    1295    1260
   l    1295    1295    1190
   m    1295    1295    1260
   n    1250    1250    1220
   o    1200    1200    1160
   p    1180    1180    1070
   q    1030    1030    990
```

I want to retain only those rows based on data in Column_C in my dataframe which are less then equal to difference of 100 to Column_A

```
User    Col_A   Col_B   Col_C
   b    1450    1450    1440
   c    1320    1280    1225
   e    1295    1250    1200
   f    1295    1295    1250
   h    1295    1295    1260
   j    1295    1295    1260
   k    1295    1295    1260
   m    1295    1295    1260
   n    1250    1250    1220
   o    1200    1200    1160
   q    1030    1030    990
```

I am trying to work with following code to filter the rows but unable to get the desired output.

```
df<- filter(df, Col_C<=Col_A & Col_C>=Col_A-100)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `subset`

```
subset(df, (Col_A - Col_C) <= 100)

#   User Col_A Col_B Col_C
#2     b  1450  1450  1440
#3     c  1320  1280  1225
#5     e  1295  1250  1200
#6     f  1295  1295  1250
#8     h  1295  1295  1260
#9     j  1295  1295  1260
#10    k  1295  1295  1260
#12    m  1295  1295  1260
#13    n  1250  1250  1220
#14    o  1200  1200  1160
#16    q  1030  1030   990
```

Or with `filter`

```
dplyr::filter(df, (Col_A - Col_C) <= 100)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(User = structure(1:16, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q"
), class = "factor"), Col_A = c(1450L, 1450L, 1320L, 1300L, 1295L, 
1295L, 1295L, 1295L, 1295L, 1295L, 1295L, 1295L, 1250L, 1200L, 
1180L, 1030L), Col_B = c(1450L, 1450L, 1280L, 1300L, 1250L, 1295L, 
1240L, 1295L, 1295L, 1295L, 1295L, 1295L, 1250L, 1200L, 1180L, 
1030L), Col_C = c(1250L, 1440L, 1225L, 1190L, 1200L, 1250L, 1000L, 
1260L, 1260L, 1260L, 1190L, 1260L, 1220L, 1160L, 1070L, 990L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[(Col_A - Col_C) <= 100]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(User = structure(1:16, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q"
), class = "factor"), Col_A = c(1450L, 1450L, 1320L, 1300L, 1295L, 
1295L, 1295L, 1295L, 1295L, 1295L, 1295L, 1295L, 1250L, 1200L, 
1180L, 1030L), Col_B = c(1450L, 1450L, 1280L, 1300L, 1250L, 1295L, 
1240L, 1295L, 1295L, 1295L, 1295L, 1295L, 1250L, 1200L, 1180L, 
1030L), Col_C = c(1250L, 1440L, 1225L, 1190L, 1200L, 1250L, 1000L, 
1260L, 1260L, 1260L, 1190L, 1260L, 1220L, 1160L, 1070L, 990L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```